# $E \subset [0, 1]^{2}$ s.t. $m(E_{x}) = 1$ a.e. $x \in [0, 1]$. Show $m(E_{y}) = 1$ a.e. $y \in [0, 1]$.

Tags: measure-theory, product-measure

Let $E \subset [0, 1]^{2}$ be measurable and let $E_{x} := \{y \in [0, 1] : (x, y) \in E\}$, $E_{y} := \{x \in [0, 1] : (x, y) \in E\}$. If $m(E_{x}) = 1$ a.e. $x \in [0, 1]$ then show that $m(E_{y}) = 1$ a.e. $y \in [0, 1]$.

Is it true that

$$(m \otimes m)(E) = \int_{[0, 1]} m(E_{x}) dx, \quad ?$$

If so, then can I also say

$$(m \otimes m)(E) = \int_{[0, 1]} m(E_{y}) dy,$$

which must be $1$ by hypothesis? Then I want to say this implies that $m(E_{y}) = 1$ a.e. $y \in [0, 1]$. I'm not sure about the integral representations above, or even the last implication.

Comment: The last implication is obvious. Since $m(E_y) \le 1$ for $y \in [0,1]$, the fact that $1 = \int_0^1 m(E_y)dy$ implies $m(E_y) = 1$ for a.e. $y \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Also, obviously the first integral representation implies the second (by symmetry, or just any argument for the first would carry over to an argument for the second). And the first can be proven as follows: $\int_0^1 m(E_x)dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 1_{E_x}(y)dydx = \int_0^1\int_0^1 1_E(x,y)dydx = (m\otimes m)(E)$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I now see why the last implication is straightforward. The rest of what you wrote makes sense too. Thanks.